# Unable to subscribe on topic using @stomp/stompjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, stomp

Here is a part of my React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';

class Balance extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const client = new Client({
            brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/stomp',
            debug: (str) => {
                console.log(str);
            },
        });

        client.onConnect(() => {
            console.log('onConnect');
            client.subscribe('/topic/balance', message => {
                console.log(message);
            })
        });

        client.activate();
    }
...
```

It looks like connection was established according to the debug output to browser's console:

```
Opening Web Socket...
Web Socket Opened...
>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
heart-beat:10000,10000
Received data
<<< CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.2
content-length:0
connected to server undefined
```

However, I don't see a message 'onConnect' in console, which means `client.onConnect` was never fired.

Therefore I can't subscribe to a topic.

What could be a problem here?

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Comment: Can you check in browser network console if WebSocket connection is actually established?

Comment: @vijaykrishna yes, I added a screenshot from my Network tab

Answer (score 3):

According [to author it was a mix up](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs/issues/18#issuecomment-432616031) in syntax of the library.

The corrected code from my question look as the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';

class Balance extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // The compat mode syntax is totally different, converting to v5 syntax
    // Client is imported from '@stomp/stompjs'
    this.client = new Client();

    this.client.configure({
      brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/stomp',
      onConnect: () => {
        console.log('onConnect');

        client.subscribe('/topic/balance', message => {
            console.log(message);
        })
      },
      // Helps during debugging, remove in production
      debug: (str) => {
        console.log(new Date(), str);
      }
    });

    this.client.activate();
  }
...
```

I created a full working example in my [repo](https://github.com/akarasev/stomp-spring-react).